# ORBEON FORMS: DATES ARE NOT IMPORTED CORRECTLY DURING EXCEL IMPORT

Tags: orbeon

While importing data in excel which contains dates, the date fields are reported as invalid. For example 04/09/2017 in excel would appear as 42982 in relational database and the orbeon form editor would complain dates are invalid. What should i do?

I modified date property setting to [D]/[M]/[Y] without success.

Comment: Are the fields are marked as having a date type in the Excel file? We also have issue [#3395](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3395) which might be related.

Comment: Yes the date fields are marked as having date type. Yes i saw the issue [#3395](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3395) but it didn't help @ebruchez